# Does BlackBerry Tablet OS have a WYSWYG GUI design tool?

Tags: blackberry

I hope to migrate one of my apps to BlackBerry Tablet OS. Does it have WYSIWYG GUI tool that integrates with Eclipse or Visual Studio, or do have to use a HTML/CSS/JavaScript editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a WYSIWYG GUI tool for the Tablet OS, sorry. There are some excellent HTML/CSS editors out there though, you may want to look at FogCreek's latest offering : [WebPutty](http://www.webputty.net/)